# Conversion of json object to object in jmeter

Tags: json, jmeter

I have a POST API consuming JSON Object. I need to pass the JSON as body data to the API. The conversion of JSON Object to the intended class object is failing. Do we have to specify any other parameters?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify `Content-Type` header to `application/json` using `HTTP Header Manager` (add it as a child to the HTTP sampler of POST request), so that JMeter sends the POST request telling the server that the body contains JSON using the header.

Comment: I did add the HTTP Header Manager also. Still the conversion was not taking taking place. I tried sending a normal string to a POST API. It was working through jmeter. Is it due to some conversion issue or should i switch to newer version of jmeter? I think it works in jmeter 2.13 also.

Comment: might be. try with 2.13. meanwhile can you please share the HTTP sampler screen shot and ViewResultsTree screenshot showing the HTTP request with POST body? so I will try to figure out the issue

Comment: Hey Naveen. I have attached the screenshots. Please let me know if it helps.